# Требования проекта. Написание тех задания

Tags: c++, база-данных, тестирование, документация

Я написал программу на с++, которая позволяет автоматизировать работу с базой данных работников фирмы. Теперь хочу написать к проекту тех задание по стандарту [IEEE STD 830-1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements_specification) (SRS). Одним из основных пунктов этого стандарта является "Требования проекта". Возникает вопрос, как определить системные требования программы (минимальные и рекомендуемые). Как я думаю это реализовать:
1. Ограничить бд: не разрешать заполнять ее более, чем 50 работниками и подсчитать выделяемое количество памяти на них.
2. Нельзя забывать про ограничения ОС: она не запустится, если пк слабый. Указывать ли это в требованиях проекта?
3. Найти требования отталкиваясь от того, как программа использует системные ресурсы (в диспетчере задач).
Итак, сам вопрос. Как посоветуете определить эти требования?
Благодарю.

Comment: Непонятно. Если ваша программа автоматизирует работу с БД, значит БД уже есть и странно как-то ограничивать эту БД. Вы должны определить требования к своей программе, а не к БД. Хотя, если ваша программа _неспособна_ поддерживать работу более 50 пользователей - то это и является её требованием.

Comment: Как связано то, запустится или нет ОС на конкретном компьютере с вашей программой? Это требование ОС. Вы должны описать, под какими ОСями ваша программа способна работать и только.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, большое спасибо за ответ. Как я понял, мне нужно описать требования программы, не включая требования ОС. А как узнать требования моей программы (извините за тавтологию) ?

Comment: Про ОС тоже нужно написать: под какими осями ваша прога работает. Линукс, Макось, Винда, Андроид и пр. И какие конкретно версии: например, Винда 7, 8, 10, но под XP и ниже не работает. А потянет или нет эту ось компьютер пользователя - не ваше дело.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, понял. То есть указать лишь ОС, а требования к железу не стоит? Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Блин, еще как стоит указать требования к железу. Но это должны быть требования _вашей_ программы, а не требования ОС.

Comment: Например, в программе используется для вычислений набор команд AVX2. Об этом нужно написать. Без них программа работать не будет. Значит нужен процессор, поддерживающий этот набор команд.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ясно. А вот например, как узнать какие минимальные требования к ОЗУ и т.п. ?